# Small Indie Production and Insurance

Tags: producing

I'm supporting some friends for a small web series and we're trying to figure out a budget. As I research, I'm reading a lot about permits and insurance and so forth. We are not even a real production company and are mostly hiring friends and such. To what extent do we need get workers comp and other forms of insurance to make this small budget short?

- We live in Los Angeles.
- We will need permits for public locations.
- We do plan on hiring friends for cast and crew.
- We were also thinking about hiring kids but I'm starting to think that is not possible with our budget.

Answer (score 3):

I've struggled with a similar question, although everything that I have done has been so small that I've usually been able to dance around it. I'll say this, from a liability standpoint the greater the size of your cast & crew and the greater your production, the more that you want to at least look into "General Liability". If you're working with animals, pyro, a lot of moving traffic, swimming/diving, aerial cinematography, things like that. You really have to look at the scale of what you're doing. Once you move away from a one-person or small-group hobbyist into hiring cast & crew, it's time to at least talk to insurance brokers. If for no other reason than to protect yourself, your employees, and your overall production.

You want to make sure that you go through a broker who is primarily an Entertainment Insurance Broker. I could go on for hours however my knowledge here is limited. I found an article last year that really helped me with the bullet points on all of this. I used this to educate myself on what I need going forward. Check out this link...
https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/the-producers-guide-to-film-production-insurance/